# Obtain MembershipUser in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm writing a new application in ASP.NET MVC.  I've created a custom MembershipProvider that stores membership data in my own db schema.  It all works, but how do I get the MembershipUser in my application, such that I can get the user key of the logged-on user and load model classes relating to that user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
using System.Web.Security;

var user = Membership.GetUser();
```

Comment: you still need a reference to System.Web.ApplicationServices (4.0) to be able to access any MembershipUser properties

Comment: its giving HttpException with additional information 'Unable to connect to SQL Server database'. Any Ideas what am I missing ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the static [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) class to retrieve the user using [GetUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx).  You'll need to configure your provider in the web.config file.   On logon you get the username from, presumably, a text box on your form.  Once logged on you can get it from the controller's User property.

```
string username = this.User.Identity.Name;
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser( username );
```

Comment: I've subsequently found that you don't need the username because Membership.GetUser() just returns the current logged-on user.